# XMPP libraries for Ruby

Tags: ruby, client, xmpp

There are several XMPP client libraries for Ruby available, what is your experience with them and which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of thing are you looking to write in XMPP? The choice very much depends on what you want to do. These are the ones I have had experience of:

- XMPP4R is one of the most popular. However the project is no longer [actively maintained](https://mail.gna.org/public/xmpp4r-devel/2010-11/msg00003.html). I've always found the API to be a little clunky.
- Blather, really cool DSL for writing things. Relies on EventMachine, so nice, fast and simple. However may not play nicely if you want to use in a non-evented webserver (like Passenger). It is also difficult to work with in an IRB console, which can make experimenting harder.

There are a few projects which build upon these base libraries for creating things like bots, Although I've no experience of them.

For the project I work on we communicate extensively from within Rails so use our own thing ([Jubjub](https://github.com/theozaurus/jubjub), and [xmpp_gateway](https://github.com/theozaurus/xmpp_gateway)). However the project is still in early days so don't expect the same kind of polish as from other libraries - it's just trying to solve a different problem, and works for us.